# How to move App service Certificate with the Webapps and their certificates across subscription

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I want to know how can we move an app service certificate with all the webapps.

In my case webapps contains other certificate thumbprints and it also contains App service certificates thumbprint, and we have various app services distribute in 4 RG and the app service certificate and keyvault are in another resource group, how should I move those across subscription.

Should I delete all the certificates from the webapps and then move them?

Or should I only delete the certificate thumbprints and leave the app service certificate thumbprint into the appservice and then move them all together with the app service certificate.

I am looking for a best practice measure in this scenario anyone performed this before?

Answer (score 2):

You can move App Service Certificates to a new resource group or subscription without limitations. If you have multiple web apps that use the same App Service Certificate, first move all the web apps, then move the certificate.

Note that, you can move an App Service Certificate to a new resource group or subscription without any issues. However, if your web app includes an SSL certificate that you purchased externally and uploaded to the app, you must delete the certificate before moving the web app. For example, you can perform the following steps:

- Delete the uploaded certificate from the web app
- Move the web app
- Upload the certificate to the web app

Refer the [App Service limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#app-service-limitations) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I delete the all the certificates from the webapp and then move everything together to different subscription, then upload all the certificates??

Deleting all the certificates from the webapp will not delete the app service certificate resource right??